Canonical Question for "What can I do about having sent a transaction without fee that takes forever to confirm?"
This is basically a note to myself or another interested person to find a good question that may serve as a canonical question-answer pair for the above issue. It was just asked yet again, which might be the thousandth time I've seen it asked. ;)
help unconfirmed for a day


Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?

Probably has the most canonically worded question title, although this is another good option.

I think a good answer could reference either/both of the below question as well:

Do unconfirmed transactions expire?
How do miners select which transactions to include in a block?


Thanks, that one fits perfectly!

I also just found

What happens if my transaction is not accepted because I did not pay fees?

of which I like the answer for being a bit more elaborate. No time right now, to further explore though.
